# Function in SQL that will give me a unique int?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to enter a row into one of my databases, but I want to make sure the primary key I give it is unique. My primary key is an int. I have tried using `newid()`, but that does not give me an int back. If there is a way I can get `newid()` to return just an int, or if another function that would give me an unique int I would use it.

Comment: And why not use `identity`?

Answer (score 3):

You could alter the definition of your column to `int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY`, then don't specify a value when inserting a row, and the ID will auto-increment.

See https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful with a random primary key, especially if it's the clustered index too. It's likely to cause allot of filesystem IO.
Use an auto incrementing identity instead.

Answer (score 1):

One object that gives unique ints are the [sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/next-value-for-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

You first need to create a sequence :

```
CREATE SEQUENCE MyNewID START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;
```

And then you can retrieve your new ID calling NEXT VALUE every time :

```
SET @MyNewID = NEXT VALUE FOR MyNewID;
```